# Select the values from a JSON aray list from a column in a table

Tags: arrays, joomla

I need to run a query on a column of a table row to return the data as a list, the data in question is formatted as a JSON array, how do I select all the 'names' as name and values as a value to display as a list?

The table is produced from a Joomla 4 CMS using the custom fields if that is of any help.

the data in the column is formatted this way

```html
{"multiple":0,"options":{"options0":{"name":"Select Make","value":"Select"},"options1":{"name":"Abarth","value":"Abarth"},"options2":{"name":"Alfa Romeo","value":"Alfa Romeo"},"options3":{"name":"Audi","value":"Audi"},"options4":{"name":"BMW","value":"BMW"},"options5":{"name":"Chevrolet","value":"Chevrolet"},"options6":{"name":"Chrysler","value":"Chrysler"},"options7":{"name":"Citroen","value":"Citroen"},"options8":{"name":"Cupra","value":"Cupra"},"options9":{"name":"DS","value":"DS Automobiles"},"options10":{"name":"Dacia","value":"Dacia"},"options11":{"name":"Daewoo","value":"Daewoo"},"options12":{"name":"Daihatsu","value":"Daihatsu"}}}
```

I have tried this query, but it returns nothing

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('name', 'name', 'value', 'value') `fieldparams`FROM `josl2_fields` WHERE `title`='manufacturer'
```

[Column in a table row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0esmx.png)

[MYSQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tEkb.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please create a [mcve] by declaring the necessary tables and data in a https://phpize.online demo so that volunteers can immediately tool with realistic data.  Joomla questions are welcome on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: It would be best for you to explicitly state your exact desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this (in joomla to), I transform all the JSON in array with json_decode first, and I browse the array

Comment: Thank you, that has given me the info I needed to start,  but for some reason, I am getting Null results